# AWS Glue Scala - split script into several scala files

Tags: scala, aws-glue

I don't get how I can split the glue script into several scala files. I am aware that one prerequisite is to reference the "other scala file" in the "Referenced files path" and define it in its own package to import it as follows in the main glue script

```
import com.mypackage.FileConfig

object glueJob {

   def main(sysArgs: Array[String]) = {

   val obj = new FileConfig()
}
```

As mentioned before the S3 ARN of FileConfig.scala would be listed in "Referenced files path" and FileConfig would be in the package mypackage, e.g.

```
package com.mypackage

class FileConfig {
}
```

Still, Glue is never able to locate the FileConfig class. Here is the error

> object FileConfig is not a member of package com.mypackage    import
> com.capitalone.FileConfig           ^SFGlueJob.scala:54: error: not
> found: value FileConfig        val tmp = new FileConfig()

Comment: 'Still, Glue is never able to locate the FileConfig class no matter what I try. - what's your error? You haven't actually told us what the problem is here or how you've asserted that.

Comment: True, I added the error message

Answer (score 0):

- Double-check that the S3 ARN you're specifying for the "Referenced files path" points to the exact location of the FileConfig.scala file. Any typos or missing details can lead to Glue not finding the file.
- Check if there are any conflicting classpath entries in your Glue job configuration.
- Make sure the FileConfig class is declared within the mypackage package as you mentioned.
- Ensure that the package name specified in the "Referenced files path" matches the package declaration within the FileConfig.scala file.
- Scala package names are case-sensitive. Verify that the casing of the package name matches in both locations.

Refer to AWS documentation: The AWS documentation provides detailed information on using referenced files and packaging for Glue jobs. Refer to the following resources for further assistance:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-scala.html

Comment: I copy the ARN via the Copy Arn feature in the AWS Console instead of typing it to avoid any errors. Also I did read the documentation you linked but did not find a solution to my compilation issue

Comment: Sorry, can't think of what else you could be missing at this time. Just to troubleshoot could you see what all directories and files glue can list - maybe the libraries are loaded into a /tmp folder and you will have to reference them with tmp. ?

Comment: The thing is I am pointing to config files in the Referenced files path just fine. The problem is the scala compilation process isn't "seeing" the other scala files even though I am adding them to the Referenced files path. I am wondering if this is a general issue with Scala Glue jobs.